# qemu and raspberry - no network interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, qemu

I managed to start a raspbian in a qemu envrionment

```
$ qemu-system-arm -machine "raspi2" -kernel kernel7.img -sd 2015-11-21-raspbian-jessie.img -dtb bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb -append "ro loglevel=5 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" -nographic
```

but for no obvious reasons I do not have any network interface but `lo`:

```
$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

There is no problem with network interfaces on other (x86_64, livecds) images.

It looks like my `/etc/network/interfaces` looks good

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Any ideas what to check or how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected -- currently QEMU's raspi2 model does not include a model of the USB controller, and ethernet on the raspi2 connects to the USB controller, so there is no ethernet support in QEMU for this board model.

Comment: Where to read about it? What about raspi3b?